# After Creating Celery Task It is Throwing error Model Object is not Json serializable even though It is not Creating docs in db

Tags: python, asynchronous, backgroundworker, django-celery

```
attach_documents_to_project.delay(
    instance=current_project,
    created=True,
    request_data=request.data)
```

The above code is in my .view.py file where I am calling celery task.

```
@shared_task
def attach_documents_to_project(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        request_data = kwargs.get('request_data')
        if created and request_data:
            attachments_data = request_data.get('document')
```

This is my tasks.py file where I am using this req.data to manipulate further.